# ApplicationException in thread not triggering validation style in WPF C# app

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, validation, exception

I'm working on an app that allows the user to enter an ID value that needs to conform to certain standards.  In the view model I have a property to hold this value that does some initial validation (which works just fine) and then starts a thread that automates look up of the entered value in another system.  This final portion is slower so I've placed it in another thread.  The issue is that when the `ApplicationException` is thrown in that thread it does not trigger the validation style on the text box in the form.  Here's what my property looks like:

```
    private string idNumber;
    public string IdNumber
    {
        get { return idNumber; }
        set
        {
            idNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IdNumber");
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(idNumber))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("The ID Number is required.");
            }
            if (idNumber.Length < 8)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("The ID Number should be 8 alphanumeric characters.");
            }
            Thread Validate = new Thread(ValidateIdNumber);
            Validate.Start();
        }
    }
```

Not that it seems to matter all that much, but here is what is happening in that thread:

```
    private void ValidateSecurity()
    {
        if (this.BadIdNumbers.Contains(this.IdNumber))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("The ID Number you have entered is on either the Bad ID Number list.");
        }

        OurAutomationLibrary AutomatedApp = new OurAutomationLibrary(this.user, this.pass);
        AutomatedApp.Get(this.IdNumber);
        if (AutomatedApp.GetFile().Contains("ID-NOT-ON-FILE"))
        {
            AutomatedApp.Quit();
            throw new ApplicationException("The ID Number you have entered is not on file.");
        }

        if (AutomatedApp.Read(2, 70, 5).Trim() == "")
        {
            AutomatedApp.Quit();
            throw new ApplicationException("This ID Number is below $1.00.");
        }
        AutomatedApp.Quit();
    }

}
```

So, is it possible to get this `ApplicationException` routed to that textbox somehow such that it triggers the validation style?

Again, the initial validations work, but the later ones do not.  Also, I need to move that collection check up to the initial validations in the set.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is that you are using exceptions wrong. Exceptions should not be used to trigger logic. You need to find a way without using exceptions to pass validation data back. What you are doing now is throwing an exception in the thread, which causes the thread to abort since you are not catching it anywhere (that I can see).

Answer (score 0):

Bind a property in UI and update that property with exception message.